# mongodb aggregate with match, lookup and project

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm new to node js with mongodb programming. I'm using `mongodb` module and I want to perform a post "join" with user public info. The code I'm using right now is as follows:

```
db.collection('post').aggregate({ 
  '$match': { category: 'video', status: 'online' },
  '$lookup': 
   { 
     from: 'user',
     localField: 'user',
     foreignField: '_id',
     as:'user'
  },
  '$project': 
     { text: 1,
       imgs: 1,
       video: 1,
       datetime: 1,
       user: 1,
       category: 1,
       marketplace: 1,
       tags: 1 } }
})
.toArray(function(err,posts){console.log(posts)})
```

but nothing works. I only get posts even if category is not `music` and the lookup does not bind the object to the result array.

**UPDATE**
the aggregate doesn't work even if letting the $match parameter only as the aggregate query

the collections returned are

```
[
  {
    "_id":"5aed6cbbd8362bcc0f2d95ab",
    "category":"music",
    "video":"",
    "imgs":[],
    "videoImage":false,
    "text":"post text",
    "tags":{["first","try"]}, 
    "datetime":1525509307968,
    "user":"FuRRTBEYBmCSDPJkN",
    "status":"online","marketplace":null}, 
  { 
    "_id":"5aedc26c6defa3d3a6de7126", "category":"music",
    "video":"https://www.youtube.com/embed/1yvLYJ2Fe_c", 
    "imgs" [],
    "videoImage":"https://i.ytimg.com/vi/1yvLYJ2Fe_c/hqdefault.jpg",
    "text":"second post text second post text second post text ",
    "tags":{["second","post"]},
    "datetime":1525531244425,
    "user":"FuRRTBEYBmCSDPJkN",
    "status":"online",
    "marketplace":null
   }
]
```

the expected results would be

```
[
  {
    "_id":"3aed6cbbd8362bcc0f2d95ab",
    "category":"video",
    "video":"",
    "imgs":[],
    "videoImage":false,
    "text":"post text",
    "tags":{["first","video"]}, 
    "datetime":1525509307968,
    "user": {_id: 'FuRRTBEYBmCSDPJkN', username: 'user1',img: '/path/to/the/image.png'},
    "status":"online","marketplace":null}, 
  { 
    "_id":"4aedc26c6defa3d3a6de7126", "category":"video",
    "video":"https://www.youtube.com/embed/1yvLYJ2Fe_c", 
    "imgs" [],
    "videoImage":"https://i.ytimg.com/vi/1yvLYJ2Fe_c/hqdefault.jpg",
    "text":"second video ",
    "tags":{["second","video"]},
    "datetime":1525531244425,
    "user":{_id: 'FuRRTBEYBmCSDPJkN', username: 'user1',img: '/path/to/the/image.png'},
    "status":"online",
    "marketplace":null
   }
]
```

---

Comment: The `"as"` property is the name of a field to output in, and not the selection of a fields to return. There are very clear examples already posted on this site as well as the documentation. Post sample documents from each collection that would actually "join" to each other for any hope of someone being able to assist you with this.

Comment: ok. thank you. even after this edit, nothing changed anyway.

Comment: Again, show you collections. The `$lookup` operation is expecting the `localField` value of `"user"` to contain **exactly the same** value which is in the "collection" called `"user"` ( which is the `from` ) on the `"_id"` field as in `foreignField`. Typically this means an `ObjectId` value, so make sure that is what both have and that they match. Meaning one of them cannot actually be a string.

Comment: **Show your collections**. Seriously if you don't then the question will have to be closed. You don't know what you're doing and in order for others to help you we actually need to "see the data". Adding bold **EDIT** statements every few minutes is not going to help anyone to answer your question. We cannot help with what we cannot see.

Comment: hmmm, how _if letting the $match parameter only as the aggregate query_ you expect a document with `"category":"music"`. When you $match `category: 'video'` expecting anything but 'video' in the category is wrong.

Comment: The problem is that if I $match `category: 'video'` I get the documents having `category:'music'` also. it seems that the $match doesn't filter in this case.

Comment: The real problem is you **expect** category:'music' . At least it is how I read "the expected results would be" snippet of code. The $match is not applied is just because of wrong syntax of the pipeline, which should be an array of stages and it is much simpler to fix than communication issues.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I updated the "expected result".

Comment: @DarioRusignuolo, good, what about the other part of my comment? Have you tried an **array** pipeline? Like in the examples at https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/

Comment: it works with array!!! Thank you @AlexBlex

Answer (score 0):

Like Alex said in the comment, the solution for my problem is to pass the **array** pipeline to the aggregate function like below.

```
db.collection('post').aggregate([
  '$match': { category: 'video', status: 'online' },
  '$lookup': 
   { 
     from: 'user',
     localField: 'user',
     foreignField: '_id',
     as:'user'
  },
  '$project': 
     { text: 1,
       imgs: 1,
       video: 1,
       datetime: 1,
       user: 1,
       category: 1,
       marketplace: 1,
       tags: 1 } }
])
.toArray(function(err,posts){console.log(posts)})
```